# ANTICONF ERROR: cannot install V8 R package

Tags: r, installation

I'm trying to install V8 rpackage on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.
The version of R used is R 3.5.1.
I proceeded as follows:

1. I installed libv8 by typing : sudo apt-get install -y libv8-3.14-dev
2. I type this command to install in R : install.packages("V8")

Then, I received this error:

```html
package ‘V8’ correctement décompressé et sommes MD5 vérifiées
Using PKG_CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/v8-3.14
Using PKG_LIBS=-lv8
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because was not found. Try installing:

deb: libv8-3.14-dev (formerly: libv8-dev) (Debian, Ubuntu)
rpm: v8-314-devel (formerly: v8-devel) (Fedora, EPEL)
brew: v8@3.15 (OSX) -- NOT regular v8! Tap from homebrew/versions
csw: libv8_dev (Solaris)
To use a custom libv8, set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘V8’

removing ‘/opt/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.1.0/envs/mro_env/lib/R/library/V8’
restoring previous ‘/opt/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.1.0/envs/mro_env/lib/R/library/V8’
Warning message:
In install.packages("/home/ben/Bureau/miniCRAN/src/contrib/V8_1.5.tar.gz", :
l'installation du package ‘/home/ben/Bureau/miniCRAN/src/contrib/V8_1.5.tar.gz’ a eu un statut de sortie non nul
```

Then, I check if i have installed libv8 correctly by typing:

```
(mro_env) root@ben-Aspire-E5-575G:/opt/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.1.0# find /lib* /usr/lib* -name 'libv8'
```

/usr/lib/libv8.so
/usr/lib/libv8.so.3.14.5

And

```
(mro_env) root@ben-Aspire-E5-575G:/opt/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.1.0# ldconfig -p | grep libv8
```

libv8.so.3.14.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libv8.so.3.14.5
libv8.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libv8.so

but when I verify if libv8.pc exists in /usr/lib/pkgconfig/ I didn't find it.

I'm stuck and I do not know how I can solve this problem.

Comment: Did you do as the anticonf output suggested and manually do `R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'` ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No I didn't this , but what  am I going to put as an argument in INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR ? and what what are their meanings ?

Comment: the full directory paths to where the include files and library files are for the V8 package, respectively

Comment: I typed it , but I get error in compilation :

Comment: make: *** [/opt/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.1.0/envs/mro_env/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:167: RcppExports.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘V8’
* removing ‘/opt/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.1.0/envs/mro_env/lib/R/library/V8’

Answer (score 2):

Try [this in R](https://ropensci.org/blog/2020/11/12/installing-v8/#installing-v8-on-linux-the-alternative-way) from Jeroem Ooms:

> ```
> # For Linux: download libv8 during installation
>
> Sys.setenv(DOWNLOAD_STATIC_LIBV8=1)
> install.packages("V8")
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the good edits @tomerikoo - definite improvement!

Comment: No problem! It is important to quote properly to make it clear that this is not your content. You already provided the link and even the name of the author, I just added proper formatting of the code and the quote. Oh and please avoid signatures and greetings