# Not able to install V8 package on ubuntu?

Tags: r, r-package

I am trying to install V8 package on ubuntu but i am getting below error:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘V8’ had non-zero exit status
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: There should be some output after `install.packages("V8")`, but before the warning message you listed. It will be impossible to diagnose your problem without that intermediate output.

Comment: yes sorry for incomplete message.plese find the below one:


ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/nk/curl
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘curl’ is not available for package ‘V8’
* removing ‘/home/nk/V8’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘V8’ had non-zero exit status

i tried to install curl as well but getting same error

Comment: i am getting below message while installing using terminal :


Package libcurl-dev is a virtual package provided by:
  libcurl4-openssl-dev 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8
  libcurl4-nss-dev 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8
  libcurl4-gnutls-dev 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'libcurl-dev' has no installation candidate

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but still after installing libcurl4-openssl-dev i am not able to install V8 getting below error :

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘V8’
* removing ‘/home/nk/V8’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘V8’ had non-zero exit status

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need some system dependencies. `V8` depends on the R package `curl`. To resolve `curl`'s system dependencies, open a terminal via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> and use

```
sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

`V8` itself also has a system dependency which you can resolve after opening a terminal and using

```
sudo apt install libv8-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sys.setenv(DOWNLOAD_STATIC_LIBV8=1)
install.packages("V8")
```

Source :- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53226904/anticonf-error-cannot-install-v8-r-package/69967726#69967726)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it installing `r-cran-curl`. It installs all R packages required for Rcurl, including V8, and also all system library dependencies

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install r-cran-curl
```